# Calculating the x, y coordinate a set distance between two points

Tags: trigonometry, coordinate-systems, parametric, interpolation

I'm trying to calculate the x and y coordinates that are a set distance between the coordinates of two pixels in an image.

For example, if I travel from my original location (x1=4, y1=3) to a new location (x2=4, y2=11), it is pretty straight-forward to calculate that these points are 8 pixels apart:

```
import math
x_dist = (x2 - x1)
y_dist = (y2 - y1)
distance = math.sqrt(x_dist * x_dist + y_dist * y_dist)
```

However, I'm having difficulty working out the coordinate that is 2 pixels along this path. I know that in this case the answer should be x=4, y=5, however I can't seem to work out how to do this. Most of the equations I've looked at on interpolation require you to know x or the y coordinate you're searching for, and finding the midpoint coordinate doesn't help much either.

**EDIT** Thank-you Arpan for your amazing help, this is how I've implemented your suggestion in Python. I've also calculated the midpoint to check that the answer was corect:

```
import math

def calc_distance(x1, y1, x2, y2):
    x_dist = (x2 - x1)
    y_dist = (y2 - y1)
    return math.sqrt(x_dist * x_dist + y_dist * y_dist)

x1, y1, x2, y2 = 0, 3, 2, 11

distance = calc_distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
first_point_dist = distance / 2

mid_x, mid_y = (x1 + x2) / 2, (y1 + y2) / 2

x_diff = x2 - x1
y_diff = y2 - y1
if x_diff == 0:
    new_x = x1
    if y_diff > 0:
        new_y =  y1 + dist_to_point
    else:
        new_y =  y1 - dist_to_point
elif y_diff == 0:
    new_y = y1
    if x_diff > 0:
        new_x = x1 + dist_to_point
    else:
        new_x = x1 - dist_to_point
else:
    tan_angle = y_diff / x_diff
    angle = math.atan(tan_angle)
    new_x = round(x1 + first_point_dist * math.cos(angle))
    new_y = round(y1 + first_point_dist * math.sin(angle))

print(new_x, new_y, mid_x, mid_y, distance)
```

**Final Edit** I just realised that the angle had to be in radians, NOT degrees, I was converting it to degrees but ending up with strange answers, that has been modified now and seems to be working well. Thanks for all the help!

**Final Final Edit** Forgot to check if the points on the same x or y axis were positive or negative.

Comment: It would be better to calculate the square of the distance. That way, you wouldn't have to invoke the (computationally expensive) routine "sqrt".

Comment: I tried that with one of my other programs written in C++ and didn't notice that much of a difference in speed, but then I think the main bottleneck in the video was reading in and creating image matrices from 4K video. It might be worth trying again to see if I get a bit of a speed up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the parametric form.

Given your initial point $(x_0,y_0)$ and another point of the line $(x_1,y_1)$, you can write the slope of line as $$\tan\theta=\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$$

For a point $(x,y)$ at a distance $r$ along the line from $(x_0,y_0)$,
$$x=x_0+r\cos\theta,y=y_0+r\sin\theta$$
Where $\tan\theta$ is the slope as above.

Comment: Will it cause problems if the tanθ equals a division by zero?

Comment: Yes but then the meaning of the two points having the same x coords makes the distance easy

Comment: Good point, thank-you so much for the help!

Comment: @Arpan maybe you can help me with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548841/calculate-point-coordinates